# Image grayscale using glide library

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I am using glide library to load image url in image view.

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageurl)
                .apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
                .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

Actually, the image is loaded fine with rounded image.

I need the image to be loaded with rounded + **grayscale** image

Can this be done by using glide lib?

Comment: what had you done for grayscale? Add a grayscale  style or image above your image view it may work

Comment: this may help you [glide-transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/glide-transformations)

Comment: thanks nilu, im trying to use it.

Comment: Why do you need Glide? You can use a ColorMatrix for that.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use Android's **android.graphics.ColorMatrix** class to set the saturation to 0 for making an ImageView grayscale.

You can achieve what you want in two steps.
1. Use Glide to make the ImageView rounded. 
2. After that use ColorMatrix class to make the ImageView grayscale.

```
Glide.with(context)
.load(imageurl)
.apply(RequestOptions.circleCropTransform())
.into(holder.thumbnail);

ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);
ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
holder.thumbnail.setColorFilter(filter);
```

Comment: Superb. Actually i was using 

   MultiTransformation multi = new MultiTransformation(
                    new GrayscaleTransformation(),
                    new CropCircleTransformation());

            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(imageurl)
                    .apply(bitmapTransform(multi))
                    .into(holder.thumbnail);

But, Your answer works like charm.

Comment: You're just awesome. No more flicker that I had with Glide-transformations lib!!

Comment: this is not working for me when download image from url

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Kotlin**:

```
            //Grey scale
            val colorMatrix =  ColorMatrix();
            colorMatrix.setSaturation(0.0f);
            val filter =  ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
            itemView.thumb.colorFilter = filter;
```

Comment: Well, if you use Kotlin you don't need to use `;`.