# How can I change color for all pixels to gray scale after I capture the picture from camera?

Tags: java, android

I took a picture from camera then i return the result in a bitmap.
I need to display the photo in Grayscale.

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Sam! Welcome to stackoverflow; please perform a search and you will find that there are plenty of answers that will point you in the right direction, here at SO or even any search engine: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381514/android-converting-color-image-to-grayscale

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image grayscale using glide library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144824/image-grayscale-using-glide-library)